# Regex to match a string only if a string does not exist

Tags: regex, oracle

Can anyone suggest me a solution in Regular Expression, to match a string if it does not exist in the given string.

Suppose I have a String

> Rohan is going to Home

and I don't want that

> Going to

string should exist, then it will not return. But if the string does not contain contains "going to", then string will be returned

**Valid**

- Rohan is at Home

**Invalid**

- Rohan is going to Home

I have heard that regex isn't well suited to negate something (except a single character). Regex is more intended to match strings, not "not match" them. Still if someone have solution please suggest in Regular Expresion

I have tried to create a Regular Expression,but didn't get success till now.

```
SELECT   1 
  FROM   DUAL 
 WHERE   REGEXP_LIKE (' Rohan is 12 home'
                       , '^\s[^going to])$','i');
```

Comment: Can't you just search for the string and invert the result? e.g. `testStr NOT LIKE '%going to%'`

Comment: @Lorax:Sir, i am looking for a solution just for my knowledge in Regular Expression

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, which uses a negative look ahead:

```
^(?!.*going to.*$)
```

Comment: :It does not return any row`    SELECT   1 
      FROM   DUAL 
     WHERE   REGEXP_LIKE (' Rohan is at home', '^(?!.*going to)','i'); `.

Comment: :Can you please do a favor .Please xplain this .

Comment: @GauravSoni Oracle doesn't support look ahead yet.

Comment: @VincentMalgrat:Ok thanks ,nyways i am now trying to understand this Backward lookahead.

Comment: @GauravSoni From what I've understood, lookaheads allow the matching of an expression that is preceded (or followed) by another expression. By opposition, negative lookaheads allow the matching of an expression that **is not** preceded by another expression. These allow the definition of expressions that weren't possible without lookaheads.

Answer (score 0):

Check out negative lookaheads.